# Assign value before save only when param is unpassed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to assign a value when a record is saved only if no key is passed for that param. I've tried 2 different ways and each way the value is assigned to 'uncategorized' even if the category param is passed. In both cases I want the current user assigned and the user will never pass a different value (this is working).

I have 2 questions: (1) why is the value always set to uncategorized even when it's passed and (2) is the controller the best place for this operation?

Attempt 1 (also tried with `.has_key?(:category)`:

```
def create
  @entry = Wiki.new
  check_and_assign_values
if @entry.save(wiki_params)
...
def wiki_params
  params.require(:wiki).permit(:content, :category, files: [])
end

def check_and_assign_values
  @entry.created_or_modified_by = "#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}"
  @entry.category = 'uncategorized' unless params[:category].present?
end
```

Attempt 2 (I thought the param might overwrite if passed):

```
def create
  @entry = Wiki.new(
    created_or_modified_by:"#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}",
    category: 'uncategorized')
if @entry.save(wiki_params)
...
def wiki_params
  params.require(:wiki).permit(:content, :category, files: [])
end
```

**Edit:** I think the root of my problem might actually be somewhere else. With the following code, the category param is passed as part of the hash, but is never inserted into the DB:

```
def create
  @entry = Wiki.new(merged_params)
  if @entry.save!
    flash[:success] = 'Your article has been created'
    redirect_to proc { wiki_url(@entry) }
  else
    flash[:error] = @entry.errors.full_messages.each { |e| e }
  end
end

private

def wiki_params
  params.require(:wiki).permit(:content, :category, files: [])
end

def user_full_name
  "#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}"
end

def merged_params
  @category = (params[:category] || 'uncategorized')
  wiki_params.merge!(created_or_modified_by: user_full_name, category: @category)
end
```

Console result:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S2lV2r3WysQpjn4b9OTgbBMIqYzMSQPdEgwtiCvTKya/fEpP5DqraMgUDDdi+VXJKNB5l0E0Qf9iM8k9JDuFhQ==", "wiki"=>{"content"=>"ital content *ital*", "category"=>"cate"}, "commit"=>"submit"}
...
Wiki Create (3.0ms)  INSERT INTO "wikis" ("created_or_modified_by", "content", "markdown_content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_or_modified_by", "Jane doe"], ["content", "ital content *ital*"], ["markdown_content", "<p>ital content <em>ital</em></p>\n"], ["created_at", "2018-02-04 12:55:32.499462"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-04 12:55:32.499462"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/wikis_controller.rb:15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def create
  @entry = Wiki.new(wiki_params)
  @entry.category = 'uncategorized' if @entry.blank?
  @entry.created_or_modified_by = current_user.full_name
  if @entry.save
    flash[:success] = 'Your article has been created'
    redirect_to proc { wiki_url(@entry) }
  else
    flash.now[:error] = @entry.errors.full_messages
    render :new
  end
end

private

def wiki_params
  params.require(:wiki).permit(:content, :category, files: [])
end
```

And this in your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, I adapted your answer, but I'm not able to persist `category`. It's just not saving as part of the commit

Comment: Also you shouldn't be merging params, overall this code looks way overcomplicated. You can just do...

Comment: I changed my answer to simplify things

Comment: You also don't need the `.each { |e| e }` on your error flash. That doesn't do anything

Comment: The way the model is set up, the user doesn't own the wiki entry so I wasn't able to refactor the full_name into the model, but I see where you are going

Comment: This all works great! Just needed one change `@entry.category = 'uncategorized' if params[:category].blank?`. Thank you very much for the help, I was pulling my hair out a little bit

Comment: Nice! One question though, an association isn't required to refactor full name. `User` can be unrelated to `Entry` and it will work. I'm glad the other stuff works though.

Comment: I can make it work if I do `def self.full_name(user)
    "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  end` in the model and then `@entry.created_or_modified_by = Wiki.full_name(current_user)` in the controller. Is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm... the code I wrote should be exact, as long as `current_user` is an instance of `User` model.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb, I wrote the method on the wrong model. You are correct, it assigns the user name as you wrote it

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your code in check_and_assign_values method.
It should be like 
`def check_and_assign_values
     @entry.created_or_modified_by = "#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}"
     @entry.category = 'uncategorized' unless params[:wiki][:category].present?
end`
Check the how category params is accessed.

Comment: I some other problems that were stopping the record from being saved, but ultimately you were correct on this point, I was referencing the param wrong.